# Angular 6 - html element background color does not change with component

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

I have a login page and I cannot color its background. I was able to color the app-login (name of my login component) element by adding

```
:host {
      display: block;
      background-color: blue
}
```

to my scss file. It was suggested in [here](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/solving-a-styling-issue-for-rendered-components-in-angular/)

But only the background of component element is colored. The other parts of the page remains white. I can color the html element on browser 
while inspecting. I added `background-color:blue;` to `html{}` tag.

I did the same thing on my .scss file but it didnt work. I also tried with !important but it still is not working.

My login.component.scss file:

```
:host {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
  }
html{
    background-color: blue !important; // not working
}
.card-container.card {
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 50px 60px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 20px 25px 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 25px;
    margin-top: 220px; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

> "The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the
>   template of that component."

This means everything you put in your login.component.scss affects only this particular component.

If you want to use

```
html{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

You should put it in some global styles file (by default it is src/styles.scss).

Comment: Thank you! It makes a lot sense. I am in learning process of Angular :)